# How do you add the file icon to the titlebar, and indicate that something is not saved in JavaFX on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

How do you add the file icon to the titlebar in JavaFX on Mac?
Like this:

[image]

And how do you indicate that the document hasn't been saved, like this:

[image]

In Swing, [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html) is how you do it, but is it possible in JavaFX too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341744/javafx-set-different-icons-for-the-title-bar-and-the-operating-system-task-bar

Answer (score 1):

No pre-coded solution in this answer.  The feature you request is not available out of the box with JavaFX 8.

Some approaches you could consider:

1. See: [JavaFX entirely customized windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874664/javafx-entirely-customized-windows) and the [Undecorator project](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator).  Potentially you could use something like Undecorator in conjunction with resources from [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com) to achieve what you want.

   OR
2. Another way is to use two stages layered on top of each other, the top stage being transparent and overlaying the icon on the lower stage - you would need to keep them in sync for location, size, visibility and iconification states.
3. Use a [Swing stage and application](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#WINDOWS) which implements the icon and place the JavaFX content inside the Swing stage using a [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).

Comment: I was already using 3, wondering if there was a better method.